# Insert in VB List

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, indexing, initialization

I have my VB code as below -

```
Dim vals As New List(Of String)(7)
vals.Insert (0 , "A")
vals.Insert (1 , "B")
vals.Insert (2 , "C")
vals.Insert (5 , "E") 'Here I receive error as Index must be within the bounds of the List.
                      'Parameter name: index
```

In requirement I have , I need to insert values at specific indexes but it could be random insert. I belive if I set capacity of List I should be able to insert values at index withing capacity.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(7)` in your constructor is specifying the *"Initial capacity"* of the List, not initialising 8 elements. [See MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

I think your best option is either:

1 - If your "array" size will not change (or will not change often) then use an array instead

```
Dim vals As String() = New String(7) {} 
'Dim vals(7) As String also works but is not best practise
vals(0) = "A"
vals(3) = "D"
'etc.
```

2 - Initialise the items in the same line as the constructor

```
Dim vals As New List(Of String)(Enumerable.Repeat("", 8))
vals(0) = "A"
vals(3) = "D"
'etc.
```

It seems to me that if you want to assign values at arbitrary indexes then using a List is a poor choice.

Comment: 1st would be my choice but it doesn't compile as "Error 1 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers."